# How to iterate over each item in a computed Ember array in a handlebar view

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have an controller which is an ArrayProxy and contains some computed arrays.

In coffeescript, my controller looks like so:

```
MyApp.parentController = Ember.ArrayProxy.create
  content: []
  mothers: (->
    mothers = (person for person in @get("content") when person.sex == 0)
  ).property("content")
  fathers: (->
    fathers = (person for person in @get("content") when person.sex == 1)
  ).property("content")
```

This works fine, and when I request 'MyApp.parentController.get("mothers")' from the command line I get back the expected array.

Now I want to display that set in my document, and so I want to iterate over the list of mothers:

```
<div id="parent-mothers-pool">
  {{#each MyApp.parentController.mothers}}
     {{#view MyApp.ParentView contentBinding="this"}}{{/view}}
  {{/each}}
</div>
```

This does not work, and in fact completely hangs the applications, forever spinning and without even printing any errors to the console.

Leaving ".mother" off of the #each handlebar correctly displays all the parents, as you would expect. But putting it on borks it.

How do I iterate over this computed array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define a binding in the `ParentMothersPool` view, pointing to controller's `mothers` attribute:

```
MyApp.EnclosingView = Ember.View.extend
    mothersBinding: 'MyApp.parentController.mothers'
```

Then in the template:

```
{{#each mothers}}
    ...
```

Comment: I will look into that. In the meantime, I worked out the answer to iterating over a computed property: First, the property **must** be cached, by adding .cacheable(). This stops the application from hanging (and is mentioned nowhere in the docs, natch...). Second, after the property is marked as cacheable, it will actually stop working the way I programmed it, because the property should observe each item of the array.

So the fixed syntax for the computed property is 'mothers: (...).property("content.@each").cacheable()'. This resolves the problem and the view works correctly.

Comment: So, my answer above aside, is the more typical pattern that you have to have custom views for any arbitrary collection or subgrouping you might ever choose to have? I feel like I'm starting to stack up large numbers of three-line views...

Comment: In this reply assume that your enclosing view is name after the div you included in this snippet. Obviously, the `mothers` binding should be hold by the view at the `each` scope level. You necessarily have a view containing this div.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I'm slowly getting my head around what "views" are in Ember, and in this case I had no enclosing view (the div was just a div). But it seems that Ember would have expected me to make a view that would contain the other nested views.